# Intellij Idea automatic creation of chaining setters for class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I create chaned setters in classes like:

```
public class Example {
    private String name;
    private Integer id;

    ...

    public Example withName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }
    public Example withID(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }
    ...
}
```

So initialization of instance becomes more clear (you can see the fields you've set without repetition of instance name):

```
Example example = 
    new Example()
            .withName("Walter")
            .withID(23);
```

Does [intellij-idea](/questions/tagged/intellij-idea) have refactoring / code constraction methods to build chaining initialization of class automatically?

Comment: You can use lombok's @accessors(chain=true) for this purpose. I am not sure about Intellij though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Code | Generate...` to create the setters automatically. Start with adding the fields to the class:

```
class Example {
    private String name;
    private Integer id;
}
```

Now invoke `Code | Generate...` (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> on the Mac) and select `Setter`. Choose the template `Builder` in the top of the dialog that appears. Select the fields you want to generate setters for and click `OK`.
Result:

```
class Example {
    private String name;
    private Integer id;

    public Example setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public Example setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }
}
```

If you want the setter methods to start with `with` instead of `set`, it is possible to modify the template.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, generate a constructor with fields.
2. Then right click select
       refactor and then replace the constructor with the builder.

   ```
   Example e=new ExampleBuilder().setId(1).setName("name").createExample();
   ```

[image]