# How to modify code automatically in multiple java classes?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-generation

I have an object hierarchy, or tree, for which I'd like to do two things:

1. For every node make every public field private and generate getters and setters.
2. Save all state of the tree in a  map so every time a setter or getter is invoked on one of the nodes it goes to the map and doesn't save or retrieve the state from the node itself. The way I would do this is to inject a reference to the map into every one of the nodes in the tree and have the setters and getters operate on the map.

I'm wondering if there's a way to modify my code automatically to do this. I know IntelliJ can make all public fields in a class private and generate getters and setters for one file, but is it possible to do this for many? Is it possible to do the second modification I outlined automatically?

Comment: For 1, maybe you could use regex treating java files normal text files.

Comment: could you add your tree and an example for at least one node?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using IntelliJ-template for getter/setter.
It's a pretty clear pseudo-code tool to create a custom code-generation mechanic.
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153962/idea-generate-with-method-for-java) to understand more clear

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ByteBuddy](https://bytebuddy.net/) to accomplish this.